# Using JBLAS with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

Kindly help me out on how to setup JBLAS on Eclipse with NDK already setup. If available, please provide a link for any step by step tutorial. I need details on how to build the native code to use in an Android project and An example showing how to call one of the native methods/classes from the Android code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/t1TMhQnHfTc